# jQuery slider appears as [object object] and doesn't line up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem setting up jQuery slider and ensuring that it lines up well with the rest of my elements (when it comes to spacing/positioning both vertically and horizontally to maintain consistency). In addition, it is now just appearing as [object object]. Any ideas on how I can sort this out? Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dhExk/1/

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">
      <div align="left" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
         <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px">Search By:</div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <div class="modal_field2">Park:</div>
          <select>
            <option selected="selected">Any</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_field2">Building:</div>
          <select>
            <option selected="selected">Any</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_field2">Room Type:</div>
          <select>
            <option selected="selected">Any</option>
          </select>
     </div>
      <div class="modal_field2" style="text-align: left">No of Students:</div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 20px; float: right">
        <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #000; background-color: #fff; font-size: 12px;" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>
       </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.modal_field2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 3px;
}​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 50,
        min: 20,
        max: 400,
        step: 10,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("" + ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#slider")` is a selector selecting an element with the id `slider`. You don't have an element with the ID `slider`, so there is no slider, and the slidervalue will be an object since there is an obvious error, there is no slider ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhExk/2/)